# heroku - how to enable and disable maintenance mode in procfile during build

Tags: heroku

I am using a Procfile similar to the following:

```sh
# Procfile
release: python manage.py migrate --noinput
```

before building I would like to set my heroku app in maintanence mode and after deploy I would like to disable maintenance mode.

documentation does not mention how to do this from Procfile: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/maintenance-mode

any ideas how this can be done?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?

Comment: actually not :| -> i moved that part to my cirlceCI config where I do `heroku maintenance:on --app <heroku-app-name>` and at the end do a `heroku maintenance:off --app <heroku-app-name>` . this does the same but unfortunately not in the Procfile.